# How to create a dynamic route in react with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Please am finding it difficult to create a route in react router

I want to create a route like this `<Route path="/:storeId" component={StorePage} />`
But I also have a route like this `/stores`
Any time I go to the `/:storeId` page it loads the `/users` page
Am just confuse

Here is the code

```
<Switch>
  <ScrollToTop>
    <MainLayout>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/stores">
        <Stores />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/:storeId">
        <StorePage />
      </Route>
    </MainLayout>
  </ScrollToTop>
</Switch>
```

Any help please.

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Comment: Okay

`<Switch>
  <ScrollToTop>
    <MainLayout>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/stores">
        <Stores />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/:storeId">
        <StorePage />
      </Route>
    </MainLayout>
  </ScrollToTop>
</Switch>`

Please I intentionally don't want `<Route path="/stores/:storeId" />`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there

Comment: Okay . . . Done

Comment: Your code is missing the `/user` case now. Maybe have a read of https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch and see if that helps. Specifically about the order of things

Comment: where are the users examples in your code

Comment: Hello @UdenduAbasili I actually meant `/stores` not `/users`

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/users">
        <Users/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users/:id">
        <UserById/>
      </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: So there is no way to user `/:id` instead of `/users/:id`

Comment: you can use that too but i feel `/users/:id` is a better representation. It seems like `/:id` would give you more headache since all links would technically qualify for that route

Comment: Okay, I was just try to see if I could get it done like this `/:id` cause thats the approach I wanted.

I wonder why is heard in react router

Comment: do what i did above. Just replace `/:id` but dont use exact with `/:id`